# Looping over 4 different crops to get data from USDA NASS using the API function

Tags: r

I'm very new to R, and I'm trying to loop over 4 different crops and download data for these crops using the API function from USDA NASS.

I have a list of 4 crops: corn, soybeans, rice and wheat, and I am trying to obtain state level annual price data for these four crops from USDA NASS, using the API function. I am trying to do this by using a for loop, and not have to download the data individually for each crop.

### R Codes

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(httr)
library(lubridate)
library(jsonlite)

crops<-c("CORN", "SOYBEANS", "RICE", "WHEAT")
for(i in 1:length(crops)){
  crop<-crops[i]
   #access ag land values data form nass using api
  data_url <- paste(
    "http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/api/api_GET/?key=my_API_KEY",
    "&commodity_desc=crops",
    "&short_desc=PRICE RECEIVED, MEASURED IN $ / BU",
    "&state_alpha=KS",
    "&year=2017",
    "&format=CSV",
    sep=""
  )
  download.file(data_url, destfile="cropprices.csv")
}
```

This is an illustration of my expected output

```
Year    State   Commodity   Value
2017    ALABAMA WHEAT   4.6
2017    ALASKA  CORN    4.2
2017    ARIZONA CORN    4.55
```

Comment: What is your question, specifically the current issue with your attempted loop? I do notice you never paste *crop* variable into URL.

Comment: I get an error message when I run my code. I do not get my expected illustrated output as shown in my post. And I have pasted my crop variable in the URL as; "&commodity_desc=crops"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a data frame of all pairings of U.S. states and crops using `expand.grid`. Then use `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) to iterate elementwise through data to download each respective csv. Even return a `read.csv()` of downloaded csv to build a list of data frames. You can even add *year*!

Fortunately, R has a built-in dataset for U.S. states (*state.abb*). Also, since downloading involves a loop, `Sys.sleep()` to suspend processing while data is downloading. Finally, because APIs involve third-party external processing that can fail for various reasons, a `tryCatch` is employed.

```
proc_download <- function(s, c) {
   cat(paste(s, c, "\n"))       # PRINTS CURRENT LOOPED STATE & CROP TO SCREEN

   tryCatch({
      data_url <- paste0(
          "http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/api/api_GET/?key=my_API_KEY",
          "&commodity_desc=", c,
          "&short_desc=PRICE RECEIVED, MEASURED IN $ / BU",
          "&state_alpha=", s,
          "&year=2017",
          "&format=CSV"
        )

     my_file <- paste0(s, "_", c, "_prices.csv")
     download.file(data_url, destfile=my_file)
     Sys.sleep(1)              # ADJUSTS SECONDS AS NEEDED

     df <- read.csv(my_file)
     return(df)

  }, error = function(e) {
        print(e)               # PRINTS ERROR MESSAGE TO SCREEN
        return(NA)             
  })
}

state_crops <- expand.grid(state = state.abb, crop = c("CORN", "SOYBEANS", "RICE", "WHEAT"))

# DOWNLOAD DATA AND BUILD LIST OF DATA FRAMES
df_list <- Map(proc_download, state_crops$state, state_crops$crop)
```